# How To Capture the Microphone Buffer

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, audio

I am using VOIP chatterbox app as a reference code. I am trying to get the captured audio data in C# so that i can send to network. In the Backend project  Server.h there is method which give callController object which can be used in UI. I tried to add the method which will give me audiocontroller object but the app is crashing saying Access violation executing location 0x6BE27618.

Or is there any other approach which can be used to get mic data in c# code.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on the context you're trying to use this in. For standard applications, there is an abstracted out way to do this, through the [Coding4Fun Toolkit](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/). Use the [MicrophoneRecorder](http://coding4fun.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/79022#1425409) class. It comes down to:

```
MicrophoneRecorder recorder = new MicrophoneRecorder();
recorder.Start();
// Do something - e.g. wait
recorder.Stop();
byte[] capture = recorder.Buffer;
```

Comment: i know that but i want to get the mic data from chatterbox refernce code. As right now it is just in native code i want to get that data in managed code.

Comment: I am able to get the BackEndAudio object in UI. 
In BackEndAudio class when captured data is ready i am firing event. To catch that event i am adding event listener in c# code 
But i am getting the following exception. Anyone can help in this

Unhandled exception at 0x6D8E2F15 (Msvcr110d.dll) in HeadlessHost.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00000000.

Comment: Seems to me like a nullref exception. Update your main post with the code you're using